# using spread operator in jsx expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm not sure why I can't pass a spread array as a value of an attribute in a JSX expression.

The spread operator resolves into a value which is what I believe the JSX expression is expecting: a value after evaluating the expression.

Note that I am trying to spread an array as a value in a button className attribute in my JSX:

```
....
   render() {
    const {on, className = '', ...props} = this.props
    const btnClassName = [
      className,
      'btn',
      on ? 'btn-on' : 'btn-off',
    ]

    return (
       <button
          className={...btnClassName} // this throws an error
          aria-label="Toggle"
          {...props}
        />
     )
.....
```

This works as expected:
Note that here I am passing an array (after .join() it's items) as a value in a button className attribute in my JSX:

```
....
   render() {
    const {on, className = '', ...props} = this.props
    const btnClassName = [
      className,
      'btn',
      on ? 'btn-on' : 'btn-off',
    ].join(' ')

    return (
         <button
          className={btnClassName} // this works as expected
          aria-label="Toggle"
          {...props}
        />
    )
.....
```

Many thanks

Comment: What exactly is the error thrown? Note that the 2 codes are not equivalent, a spread operator on an `array` doesn't return a string like `join` does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It throws an error because the **expected syntax is a string** with space separated class names.

You can spread an array into another array or into an argument list, but not into a string variable.

You need to join your array with spaces to get a string as output and pass it as `className`.

> This can be misleading since there is no difference when you `console.log()` an array joined with spaces with the same array but spread.

But this is only because you are spreading the array into the argument list of `console.log()`, and `console.log()` will separate each argument with spaces before printing them:

```js
const classes = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'];

const join = (...args) => args.join(' ');

console.log(...classes); // console.log() joins the arguments with a space automatically
console.log(join(...classes));
console.log(classes.join(' '));
```